# How to write typescript? Unit Testing Vue Components

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-component

How to write following code in typescript?
This code is from [Unit Testing Vue Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/unit-testing-vue-components.html#Real-World-Example).

Code:

```
const factory = (values = {}) => {
  return shallowMount(Foo, {
    data: { ...values  }
  })
}
```

Error:

```
Missing return type on function.
```

Comment: `const factory = (values = {}): Wrapper => { ... }` perhaps?

Comment: @Phil `values` is loose here, or should I say, `non-implicit any`

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I was only focusing on the return-type. Also, my TS is terrible 

Comment: @Phil I tried your suggestion, but I got an error like: `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Wrapper'`

Comment: Well yeah, you'd need to import it first

Comment: I did it after importing!